# R Equality while ignoring NAs

Tags: r

Is there an equivalent of `==` but with the result that `x != NA` if `x` is not `NA`?

The following does what I want, but it's clunky:

```
mapply(identical, vec1, vec2)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1 == NA` returns a logical `NA` rather than `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  If you want to call `NA` `FALSE`, you could add a second conditional:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:10
x[4] <- NA
y <- sample(1:10, 10)

x <= y
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

x <= y & !is.na(x)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You could also use a second processing step to convert all the `NA` values from your equality test to `FALSE`.

```
foo <- x <= y
foo[is.na(foo)] <- FALSE
foo
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Also, for what its worth, `NA == NA` returns `NA` as does `NA != NA`.

Comment: It's kind of annoying to have to do an AND, but I guess if there's no better way.

Comment: How so?  What would you propose instead?  `NA` behaves in a special way (so does `NULL`) for very important reasons!

Comment: I realize the behavior of `==` is valuable, but I wish there was an operator `=='` which behaved how I want as well. (R doesn't allow user-defined operators, right?)

Comment: @Xodarap You sure can:  `'%==%' <- function(a, b) a<=b & !is.na(a); x %==% y`.  You can also define your own class and create methods on it so that `==` for your class acts as you want it [see here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-July/167370.html)

Comment: I know this is 5 years old, but why would `NA & FALSE` evaluate to FALSE and not NA?  That seems like totally inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @thc (TRUE | «anything» == TRUE) / (TRUE & «anything» == «anything») / (FALSE | «anything» == «anything») / (FALSE & «anything» == FALSE), where «anything» can be NA. Consistent, yes; useful, idk.

Answer (score 19):

Just replace "==" with %in%.

Example:

```
> df <- data.frame(col1= c("a", "b", NA), col2= 1:3)
> df
       col1 col2
    1    a    1
    2    b    2
    3 <NA>    3

> df[df$col1=="a", ]
       col1 col2
    1     a    1
    NA <NA>   NA

> df[df$col1%in%"a", ]
       col1 col2
    1    a    1

> "x"==NA
  [1] NA

> "x"%in%NA
  [1] FALSE
```

Comment: This does not work for vector equality, i.e. you would still need to use `mapply` to identify whether each element of `vec1` is equal to the corresponding element of `vec2`.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator is often used in combination with filtering data.frames.

In that situation, `dplyr::filter` will retain only rows where your condition evaluates to `TRUE`, unlike `[`. That effectively implements `==` but where `1 == NA` evalutes as `FALSE`.

Example:

```r
> df <- data.frame(col1= c("a", "b", NA), col2= 1:3)
> df
       col1 col2
    1    a    1
    2    b    2
    3 <NA>    3

> dplyr::filter(df, col1=="a")
       col1 col2
    1     a    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use base R:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", NA), col2 = 1:3, col3 = 11:13)
df

subset(x = df, subset = col1=="a", select = c(col1, col2))
#   col1 col2
# 1    a    1
```

or with arrays:

```
df <- c("a", "b", NA)
subset(x = df, subset = df == "a")
```