# How to fix error code "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: loops, if-statement, nested-loops

I am looking to take a data set (df_freeGammas) and summarize certain components of the set. The data set is split into subjects and different test numbers (subject 1, test 1). Some subjects have more than 1 test for them. Each test has a subset of 16 rows of data corresponding to the test and subject. I want to be able to use a loop or nested loop to place the subject number in a results matrix. I have figured out a way to do this, but I keep getting the error: 
"Error in if (df_freeGammas[n, 2] != df_freeGammas[n + 1, 2]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
Please help.

I have tried adding more if loops as well as a while loop.

```
for (n in 1:nrow(df_freeGammas)){
+    if (df_freeGammas[n,2] != df_freeGammas[n+1,2]){
+         Results[n/16,1] = df_freeGammas[n,1]}
+       else if (df_freeGammas[n,1] != df_freeGammas[n+1,1]){
+           Results[n/16,1] = df_freeGammas[n,1]}
+         else 
+           invisible()
```

I expect the result but without the error message.

Comment: Can you print the value of "df_freeGammas[n,2] != df_freeGammas[n+1,2]" before the if statement? My guess is that it is evaluating to a non-boolean.

Comment: The printed value of "df_freeGammas[n,2] != df_freeGammas[n+1,2]" was NA. Do you have any suggestions in order to make a similar statement boolean? I tried switching to < and adding another if loop for the > but that didn't work.

Comment: Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though one of your equality checks is evaluating to "NA", instead of TRUE/FALSE.

One potential solution would be adding a clause for NA cases, as described [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487756/r-equality-while-ignoring-nas).

For your use case, this might look something like this:

```
(df_freeGammas[n,2] != df_freeGammas[n+1,2]) & !is.na(df_freeGammas[n,2] != df_freeGammas[n+1,2])
```

The above will only return TRUE if the two values are unequal, and the equality check evaluates to Non-NA.

As always, please be sure to mark this answer as accepted if it resolves the issue.

Thanks!