# replace values in a dataframe with nested ifelse

Tags: r, for-loop, replace

i need to replace a certain value in a data.frame, based on a condition, like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DS)){
  if (DS$Date1[i] == DS$Date2[i]){
    DS$Time2[i] <- DS$Time1[i]
  }else if (DS$Date3[i] == DS$Date2[i]) {
    DS$Time2[i] <- DS$Time3[i]
  }else if (DS$Date4[i] == DS$Date2[i]) {
    DS$Time2[i] <- DS$Time4[i]
  }else {
    DS$Date1[i] <- DS$Date2[i]
  }
}
```

but the ifelse condition is returning an error: Error in if (condition) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
Can you help me with this nested ifelse or another solution?

Comment: Hi! Welcom to Stack Overflow. It would help us if you include all the relevant information about the problem. What is `DS` (data.frame? matrix?)? What is the error?

Comment: the error is "Error in if (condition) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
DS is a data.frame

Comment: Do you have NA's? In the data? How do you want to treat them? Note that if you compare anything to NA, you get back NA, and not True or False value.

Comment: yes there is NA's in the data, but it doesn't matter for the final result. if the values match, i want to replace the time based on the date (as in the first 3 ifelse statements). if not, i want to replace the date with another one, regardless of being a NA or another valid value.

Comment: Then see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913644/3051715

Answer (score 0):

the answer, as tmrlvi posted, is to replace == with %in%, because if there is an NA statement in the dataset, it won't work as pretended.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(DS)){
  if (DS$Date1[i] %in% DS$Date2[i]){
    DS$Time2[i] <- DS$Time1[i]
  }else if (DS$Date3[i] %in% DS$Date2[i]) {
    DS$Time2[i] <- DS$Time3[i]
  }else if (DS$Date4[i] %in% DS$Date2[i]) {
    DS$Time2[i] <- DS$Time4[i]
  }else {
    DS$Date1[i] <- DS$Date2[i]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nested `ifelse` statement you can do :

```
DS$Time2 <- with(DS, ifelse(Date1 %in% Date2, Time1, 
                       ifelse(Date3 %in% Date2, Time3, 
                         ifelse(Date4 %in% Date2, Time4, Time2))))
```

To replace `Date1`, we can use

```
inds <-  with(DS, !(Date1 %in% Date2 | Date3 %in% Date2 | Date4 %in% Date2))
DS$Date1[inds] <- DS$Date2[inds]
```