# Logically compare columns in a data frame that contain NA?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, logical-operators

Relatively new to R, I discovered today that `1 == NA` returns `NA` instead of an expected `FALSE`.

I looked extensively at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487756/r-equality-while-ignoring-nas) for help, which is good, but is oriented towards vectors and I'm working with dataframes.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm working with:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- expand_grid(shpmt = c(1:3), stoptype = c("P", "D"))
df_example$metgoal.ref <- c(1,NA,0,0,1,NA)
df_example$metgoal.tri <- c(1,NA,0,1,NA,1)

> df_example

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  shpmt stoptype metgoal.ref metgoal.tri
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 P                  1           1
2     1 D                 NA          NA
3     2 P                  0           0
4     2 D                  0           1
5     3 P                  1          NA
6     3 D                 NA           1
```

My goal is to see every instance where .ref and .tri are not the same, including `NA`. I first tried a straightforward (I thought) inequality:

```
> filter(df_example, metgoal.ref != metgoal.tri)  #Returns only inequalities without NAs.
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  shpmt stoptype metgoal.ref metgoal.tri
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1     2 D                  0           1
```

Initially, I didn't realize I was missing the `NA`'s, but I now know I can get to them using `is.na()`, which is important because this construction allows me to find `NA` in **either** of the two columns (and this is why [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487756/r-equality-while-ignoring-nas) doesn't help me very much with its vectors).  Somewhat of a downside is that it also gives instances where **both** columns are `NA` (and I care primarily about them being different):

```
> filter(df_example, is.na(metgoal.ref != metgoal.tri))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  shpmt stoptype metgoal.ref metgoal.tri
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 D                 NA          NA   #Not ideal -- I want only columns that disagree.
2     3 P                  1          NA
3     3 D                 NA           1
```

If I put the two constructions together, I can get what I want, except for the dual `NA` columns in row 1:

```
> filter(df_example, is.na(metgoal.ref != metgoal.tri) | (metgoal.ref != metgoal.tri))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  shpmt stoptype metgoal.ref metgoal.tri
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 D                 NA          NA   #Still not ideal
2     2 D                  0           1
3     3 P                  1          NA
4     3 D                 NA           1
```

But that is a lot to type and maintain for what I consider to be just one inequality, and I have many of these to do for other column sets, plus I have additional conditions to add:

```
> filter(df_example, (is.na(metgoal.ref != metgoal.tri) | (metgoal.ref != metgoal.tri)) & stoptype == "D")  

#Added another condition, increasing complexity.

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  shpmt stoptype metgoal.ref metgoal.tri
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 D                 NA          NA
2     2 D                  0           1
3     3 D                 NA           1
```

I thought that perhaps the `identical()` function would be helpful, but if it can be, then I'm using it wrong and need help:

```
> filter(df_example, !identical(df_example$metgoal.ref, df_example$metgoal.tri))  

#This does not work at all -- probably using it wrong.

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  shpmt stoptype metgoal.ref metgoal.tri
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 P                  1           1
2     1 D                 NA          NA
3     2 P                  0           0
4     2 D                  0           1
5     3 P                  1          NA
6     3 D                 NA           1
```

Other strategies I have seen for this situation is to replace the `NA`'s with something that can tested for inequality in the manner I originally tried:

```
df_example2 <- df_example %>% 
  replace_na(list(metgoal.ref = 9, metgoal.tri = 9))  #Arbitrarily choosing 9 as replacement value

filter(df_example2, metgoal.ref != metgoal.tri)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  shpmt stoptype metgoal.ref metgoal.tri
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>
1     2 D                  0           1
2     3 P                  1           9
3     3 D                  9           1
```

I suspect that this last solution is the best I can possibly get, but down the line I expect to be doing aggregations and summary statistics on the `metgoal.*` columns, and it may be proper that they should remain `NA`.  I can go back to the `df_example` before I converted it, but it sticks in my mind that there's a better solution to this, and it would improve my learning.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. Please let me know what you think!

```
mapply(identical, df_example$metgoal.ref, df_example$metgoal.tri)
```

Then you can use it to filter your original data. I added `!` because you're interested in rows where these fields are NOT identical.

In tidy it might look like this

```
filter(df_example, !mapply(identical, df_example$metgoal.ref, df_example$metgoal.tri))
```

or in base

```
df_example[!mapply(identical, df_example$metgoal.ref, df_example$metgoal.tri),]
```

Comment: I did try this earlier today and it worked well inside the filter() function, even combined with the additional criteria.  I'm inclined to wait a few days to see if any other answers appear before I accept this as the answer, but could you edit your answer to show it with the filter construct?  `filter(df_example, !mapply(identical, df_example$metgoal.ref, df_example$metgoal.tri))` is exactly what worked for me to achieve the result I was trying to describe.

Comment: And just for anyone else that passes this way, the way I handled additional criteria that worked as desired was `filter(df_example, !mapply(identical, df_example$metgoal.ref, df_example$metgoal.tri) & stoptype == "D")`.

Comment: I updated my answer based on your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I greatly appreciate your help.